# How do you mock file reading in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the following code that loads edn data from my resources folder:

```
(defn load-data
  []
  (->> (io/resource "news.edn")
       slurp
       edn/read-string))
```

I'd like to test this by mocking out the file reading part, so far I have this:

```
(deftest loading-data
  (is (= (edn/read-string (prn-str {:articles [{:title "ASAP Rocky released" :url "http://foo.com"}]})) (load-data))))
```

But I know this very flaky test because if the edn file name changes or it's contents or updated, the test will fail. Any ideas?

Comment: All the answers are good, not sure which one to accept :-(

Comment: Your original question was how to mock file reading and IMHO you should accept the one that shows how to do mocking in general and how to mock in your case. But the real answer here is, that you should not do that at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock out a call to function with [`with-redefs`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs), that "Temporarily redefines Vars while executing the body". E.g.,

```
(deftest load-data-test
  (with-redefs [slurp (constantly "{:a \"b\"}")]
    (is (= (load-data) {:a "b"}))))
```

This way the `slurp` in `load-data` in the scope of `with-redefs` returns `"{:a \"b\"}"`.

Answer (score 4):

What about this function are you wanting to gain confidence for? Are you worried that news.edn won't exist? Are you worried slurping and or edn reading won't work on a resource?

My advice is to test your separate concerns separately

If you're worried about news.edn not existing assert against it's existence

If you're worried about the rest of the function not converting from edn add a new signature to accept a resource then provide another resource at test time to assert against

If you're worried about the shape of the file maybe have a test that runs against the data before it's put in news.edn

Then when you come back to these tests years later you'll see clear reasons for failures instead of a test that fell over because of N possible reasons that are unknown till debug time

Answer (score 1):

As other's have suggested: Mock less things.

It might be a reflex you learned from building Java tests.

If you have composed your functions correctly, you can test them individually without the need for side-effects (like reading a file).

If you mock `slurp` in your example, you are not testing anything meaningful: You would essentially test if the standard function `edn/read-string` works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your `load-data` to accept the name of the file to load as argument (and later call it with `news.edn` in your "main"). This makes it way more functional and this way you can easily test `load-data` the way you test it right now, but you pass down some `test-news.edn` from your test resources.  And there is no need to mock anything for the happy path.

This way you can also write test for other scenarios: what if the file is missing?  Or the .edn file is malformed.  What if you pass some resource that loads forever?  etc.